# 'tuple' object does not support item assignment on array

Tags: python, mysql, tuples

I want to get select from my db ,when I tried to change one of the cells

here is my code:

```
command = "select desc ,city,datetime,loc from mytable'"
cursor.execute(command)
result = cursor.fetchall()
i = 0
for x in result:
   myary.append(result[i])
   i= i+1

my_list = list(myary)
for y in range(0,len(myary)):
    sip = myary[y][0].split("/")
    my_list [y][0]=sip[0]
myary = tuple(my_list)
```

Output:

```
'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: For the ease of readers, you should probably add, on which line of your code this error arises. In general, if you set `a = (0, 1, 2)` and then `a[0] = 3`, this gives rise to this error: "TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment".

Comment: The problem is that `my_list[y]` is a tuple, and you’re trying to assign to an index within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[`tuples`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tuples-in-python/)*** are immutable in python. In the code you're trying to modify one. To fix it you can convert it to a ***[`list`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)***. Something like:

```py
command = "select desc ,city,datetime,loc from mytable'"
cursor.execute(command)
result = cursor.fetchall()

my_list = [list(x) for x in result]  # Convert each tuple to a list

for y in range(0,len(my_list)):
    sip = my_list[y][0].split("/")
    my_list[y][0]=sip[0]

myary = tuple(my_list)  # Convert them back to a tuple of tuples
```